# What numerical integration method, and of what order, is used by scipy.odeint?

Tags: python, scipy

I am do a project in python modelling the collisions of galaxies. I want to know what sort of numerical method is used by the scipy routine so that I can evaluate what integration methods to use for my project and write a little about it in my report. I have read the scipy documentation and it seems unclear- it appears to use something called LSODA, but I can't fully understand the explanations of that available. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LSODA uses a linear multistep method:

> LSODA, written jointly with L. R. Petzold, solves systems dy/dt = f with a dense or banded Jacobian when the problem is stiff, but it automatically selects between nonstiff (Adams) and stiff (BDF) methods. It uses the nonstiff method initially, and dynamically monitors data in order to decide which method to use. The LSODA source is commented extensively to facilitate modification. Both a single-precision version and a double-precision version are available.

([Source](http://www.oecd-nea.org/tools/abstract/detail/uscd1227))

For large-scale Hamiltonian systems (such as galaxies colliding), a [symplectic integrator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symplectic_integrator) might be a better choice.